# Elasticsearch HTTP River

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm starting to play around with Elasticsearch, and I'd like to periodically pull data via HTTP from a particular location, ideally as a river, every few seconds or so.

The particular address is a simple monitoring endpoint, and outputs some JSON about the state of it's systems. Doesn't need any authentication, just the HTTP request.

Is there a recommended way of doing this inside ES? Or, should I just put together a polling server that pull and pushes?

Comment: I'm sure you could write a relatively simple script which could do this for you?

Comment: I can, but I wanted to find out if there was a pre-existing option for ES. Seems like a useful "river" to have, and I couldn't find a listing of available rivers like there are for gems, eggs, etc.